# Is posible to obtain POST data in socket io and express js?

Tags: web-services, express, websocket, socket.io, webservice-client

I have a web service which I send POST data from an app every x time. I need to obtain those post data on the client (index.html) and pass those post data to javascript function.
Any suggestions on how to do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you 're using **ejs** as an engine template , you can access **ejs** variables from within javascript code : 
exemple : in the routes.js you did :

```
res.render('index',{data:'test'});
```

in the index.ejs file, you can access it from the `<script>` ==>

```
<script>
var data = <%= data%>;
console.log(data) // 'test';
</script>
```

learn more about ejs : 
http://www.embeddedjs.com/